# Not working on Android device after Firebase integration in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-analytics

I have an Unity game project for both mobile platforms, IOS and Android. **After Firebase Analytics integration**, it stopped running on Android devices but still working on Unity Editor.

For integration, I only imported FirebaseAnalytics.package and added the following code for initialization:

```
    Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available)
        {
            Debug.Log("Enabling data collection.");
            FirebaseAnalytics.SetAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
            Debug.Log("Set user properties.");
            FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserProperty(
            FirebaseAnalytics.UserPropertySignUpMethod,"Google");
            FirebaseAnalytics.SetMinimumSessionDuration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
            FirebaseAnalytics.SetSessionTimeoutDuration(new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0));

        }
        else
        {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format("Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you use any other Google product/service in your project?

Comment: Yes I use Google AdMob